# Wait for promises inside Promise.all to finish before resolving it

Tags: javascript, promise, es6-promise

I have a Promise.all that executes asynchronous functions mapped on an array input if it's not null and then resolve data to a previously defined Promise:

```
Promise.all((inputs || []).map(input => {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    someAsyncFunc(input)
    .then(intermediateOutput => {
      someOtherAsyncFunc(intermediateOutput )
      .then(output => {
        return Promise.resolve(output )
      })
      .catch(reason=> {
        return Promise.reject(reason)
      })
    })
    .catch(reason => {
      return Promise.reject(reason);
    })
  })
  .then(outputs => {
    resolve(outputs)
  })
  .catch(reason => {
    reject(reason)
  })
}))
```

I only get empty outputs before even someAsyncFunc finishes its work. How can make Promise.all wait for the promises inside to finish their asynchronous work ?

Comment: You are very confused about how `Promise.all()` works.  It does not accept a callback like you have it declared in your first line of code.  It accepts an array of promises.

Comment: `return Promise.all(inputs.map(someAsyncFunc));` is probably what you are looking for?

Comment: @Arthur, yes, but actually I have an other function to call just after someAsyncFunc. i'll edit my code to show that

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See jfriend's comment.

`someAsyncFunc` and `someOtherAsyncFunc` are function that properly return a promise
with something like `return new Promise(/*...*/);`

this is useless:

```
.then(output => {
  return Promise.resolve(output )
})
```

read the Promise documentation

same

```
.catch(reason=> {
  return Promise.reject(reason)
})
```

the Promise is already rejecting, you don't need to catch and reject yourself

to make sure Promises are chainable you need to return the Promise

```
// ...
return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
  if(inputs == null)
    resolve([]);
  else {
    Promise.all(inputs.map(input => {
      return someAsyncFunc(input)
        .then(someOtherAsyncFunc)
    }))
      .then(resolve)
      .catch(reject)
  }
});
```

note I would rather not make the arry for Promise.all inline, it adds visual clutter:

```
return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
  if(inputs == null)
    resolve([]);
  else {
    const myPromises = inputs.map(input => {
      return someAsyncFunc(input)
        .then(someOtherAsyncFunc)
    });
    Promise.all(myPromises)
      .then(resolve)
      .catch(reject)
  }
});
```

it may still fail if you made other mistakes.

Comment: Thank you very much for your input ! That was very clear

Comment: when i declear a var to make an loop ".map()" i got `Objects are not valid as a React child (found: object with keys {_40, _65, _55, _72}). If you meant to render a collection of children, use an array instead.`

Comment: make a new question oliver d

Answer (score 3):

Would not just

```
return Promise.all((inputs || []).map(input =>
 somePromiseFunc(input).then(someOtherPromiseFunc)
);
```

work ?

You're not using `Promise.all` right the first time since it takes an array of promises as input, and not `(resolve, reject) => { ... }`

`Promise.all` is going to be rejected as soon as one of the underlying promises fails, so you don't need to try to do something around `catch(error => reject(error)`

Example:

```
const somePromiseFunc = (input) => new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
  setTimeout(() => {
    if (input === 0) { reject(new Error('input is 0')); }
    resolve(input + 1);
  }, 1000);
});

const someOtherPromiseFunc = (intermediateOutput) => new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
  setTimeout(() => {
    if (intermediateOutput === 0) { reject(new Error('intermediateOutput is 0')); }
    resolve(intermediateOutput + 1);
  }, 1000);
});

const f = inputs => {
  const t0 = Date.now()
  return Promise.all((inputs || []).map(input => somePromiseFunc(input).then(someOtherPromiseFunc)))
    .then(res => console.log(`result: ${JSON.stringify(res)} (after ${Date.now() - t0}ms)`))
    .catch(e => console.log(`error: ${e} (after ${Date.now() - t0}ms)`));
};

f(null)
// result: [] (after 0ms)

f([1, 0])
// error: Error: input is 0 (after 1001ms)

f([1, -1])
// error: Error: intermediateOutput is 0 (after 2002ms)

f([1, 2])
// result: [3,4] (after 2002ms)
```